# How to make a CGRect slashed at bottom?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to implement the following:

[image]

A custom NavigationBar which is slashed at the bottom, how can I do this using CGRect?

Another alternative would be to make a image of it and push the list up to overlap the transparent part in the image. I'd prefer the first solution if possible tho. Any suggestions?

This is my current WIP state: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Bezier path
Just add lines and make your custom shape
like this:

```
let path = UIBezierPath()
shape.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
shape.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 320))
shape.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 94, y: 320))
shape.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 64, y: 0))
shape.close()
```

Comment: I believe you do not need that many points to achieve OP's required effect, simply drawing a triangle at the bottom will be enough. Also note that closePath() will connect the last added point to the starting, there is no need to add the original point again if ending at the start.

Comment: How does the shape get applied to the NavigationBar's current Rect? By overriding draw?

Comment: You can make a `UINavigationbar` subclass and add your view in  the `drawRect` method